# Order by по коллекции обьектов

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Всем привет. Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Допустим у нас есть такой код

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Prop1 {get; set;}
    public List<string> ListProp {get; set;}
}

Main()
{
    var objs = new List<MyClass>();

    var obj1 = new MyClass() {
        Prop1 = "hz",
        ListProp = new List<string>() { "10", "", "12", "z" }
    };

    var obj2 = new MyClass() {
        Prop1 = "hz2",
        ListProp = new List<string>() { "stc", "123", "", "33" }
    };

    var obj3 = new MyClass() {
        Prop1 = "hz3",
        ListProp = new List<string>() { "", "", "", "0.1" }
    };

    objs.add(obj1);
    objs.add(obj2);
    objs.add(obj3);
}
```

Получился лист с объектами. Теперь задача, как сделать эстетично order by по свойству ListProp?

Не знаю почему, но думал что такой код прокатит `objs.OrderBy(x => x.ListProp)` но нет.

Answer (score 3):

Откуда компилятору или исполняющей среде знать, по какому принципу сортировать списки строк?

Выделите то, для чего есть сравнение по-умолчанию:

```
objs.OrderBy(x => x.ListProp.Count);
```

Или используйте [другую версию метода](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb549422(v=vs.110).aspx) со своим компаратором.

Comment: @dim4an: Кроме того, не забывайте, что `OrderBy` возвращает _новый_ список, так что если вам нужна сортировка «in place», пользуйтесь методом `Sort`.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. 
Да, изначально не ясно выразился. Необходимо отсортировать коллекции, на основании данных в них.